# Sending session id in cookie with an api request through Swagger UI at the "Try it Out"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.4.0. I'm trying to send my custom header (session identifier) in Cookie through swagger ui doc at the "Try It Out". Here is the code

**Note: the original name of header is changed from x-xxxxx-key to x-session-key for security reason**

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("x-session-key", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "x-session-key", // Name of the cookie
        Description = "Session ID",
        Scheme = ""
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "x-session-key"
                }
            },
            new string[] {}
        }
    });    
});
```

```
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        /*c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        // Allow Swagger UI to use the sessionId cookie
        c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("x-session-key", "x-session-key");*/
    });
```

In Swagger UI, I can see "Authoreize" button, when I click it, it opens this kind of window

[image]

I'm taking my active sesison id from database and enter it to this value input.

After that, I'm sending an api request to my backend. What I can see on the backend, is that initial value that I entered in swagger UI has changed. For example,

I've entered this value `a18b554df3cd48189db83a53981a3335`

But that I can see in a browser console (and at the backend when debug) is that value changed to `b7ee0f433b2a4b0789f1843e942d2465`.

Seems like swagger UI encodes my value. What I would like to do is to send a value as it is.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Thanks.

UPDATE:

From here, I can clearly see that my session id has an original value if I get it from Headers, not from Request.Cookies

[image]

Comment: Cookies and HTTP headers are not the same thing, why are you trying to interchange them?

Comment: The example I found in the internet and based on the swagger documentation, this parameter should be in Request.Cookies and it there, but the original value is changed. My question is there anyway to configure swagger ui to send this parameter in a Cookie withoyt any additional manipulation over it.

Comment: In a postman, I'm sending request and backend returns this parameter in the cookie back to the client, the subsequent requests works like a charm. The same I'm expecting from swagger ui which has a documentation and some examples where you can use cookie to send your session id while trying to send request from swagger doc.